# How can create in JavaFX custom LookUp search widget from database

Tags: java, javafx-8

I will need create custom widget for search products from our database product table. I can create and use ComboBox widget  but there is products table many rows so as then way do not right. I will need same ComboBox itself first only show 50 rows and after LookUp search gets some data from product tables. Give me some ideas or library made for LookUp widget!

Comment: Do pagination...

Comment: Thank you for answer but my GUI do not fit it is solution

Comment: Pagination is possible with listView,table .. etc

Comment: I know , but i need same web input lookup search widget from database

Comment: I have try to make the widget but I did with bugs so I am searching ideas or  library

Comment: Use autocomplete box from controlFX.

Comment: Good solution I tried. It do not fit me too.

Answer (score 2):

You should use JFXAutoCompletePopup.
Here is a simple example of JFXAutoCompletePopup:

```
JFXTextField field = new JFXTextField();
field.setLabelFloat(true);
field.setPromptText("Type Something");

JFXAutoCompletePopup<String> autoCompletePopup = new JFXAutoCompletePopup<>();
autoCompletePopup.setSelectionHandler(event -> field.setText(event.getObject()));
autoCompletePopup.getSuggestions().addAll("Film", "Book", "Paper");
field.textProperty().addListener(observable ->{
    autoCompletePopup.filter(s -> s.contains(field.getText()));
    if(!autoCompletePopup.getFilteredSuggestions().isEmpty()){
        autoCompletePopup.show(field);
    }else{
        autoCompletePopup.hide();
    }
});
```

Regards,